# How to set the initial screen depending on first launch or not?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using AsyncStorage to detect whether it's first launch or not.

If the users launch the app for the first time, the app takes them to "TourScreen1" page. Or "Feed".

but below code is not working.

this returns object. It should return string.

Is there a way to make this code return string?

Or do I need to use another way?

```
const Initial = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Cover,
      TourScreen1,
      TourScreen2,
      TourScreen3,
      TourScreen4,
      Register: RegisterToLogin,
      Feed: TabNavigator
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: AsyncStorage.getItem("isLaunched").then(value => {
        if (value === null) {
          return "TourScreen1";
        } else return "Feed";
      })
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getItem`  returns a promise which is an object, `createSwitchNavigator` is synchronous and doesn't wait for the `getItem`'s promise to be fulfilled or rejected to finish up being executed. So, the promise is being fed to your initialRoute which is an object which is causing the error.

Coming to dynamic initialRoute values, there is no way to dynamically set the `initialRoute`
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/limitations.html#dynamic-routes

At least till `react-navigation@4.x` there is no way in any navigators of React Navigation, so to achieve so what you can do is to dynamically create the navigator itself upon your data if you want to stick to the same React Navigation's version or prefer upgrading the navigation lib to `React Navigation 5` which overcomes this limitation.
Tthe reference [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/limitations.html#dynamic-routes) mentioned above for the limitation being quoted in `React Navigation`'s official doc also contains hyperlink for the new API overcoming this limitation.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since createSwitchNavigator is synchronous as suraj said, you cant give dynamic initialroute name, What i did is ive made a splashscreen as initial page and that page would just have A logo of your app, and in that page you could have :

```
    class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
        constructor(){
            super();

        }
        componentDidMount(){
            AsyncStorage.getItem("alreadyLaunched").then(value => {
                if(value == null){
                     AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', true); // No need to wait for `setItem` to finish, although you might want to handle errors
                     this.props.navigation.navigate('FirstTimeScreen');
                }
                else{
                   this.props.navigation.navigate('UsualScreen');
                }}) // Add some error handling, also you can simply do 
        }
        render(){
           return(
<Image /> // image of app
)
    }
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks for your sincere reply. I already tried this similar way. The reason why I was trying to set dynamic initial is because when you start your app, there is a loading screen which is different from splash screen. So I have two static screen. One is loading screen, another is splash screen. I want to merge them into one screen. How do you handle loading screen? When you launch react native in the beginning, there is a default loading screen where you can see "by react native" on the bottom of the screen. How do you handle this?